# How to define a generic responce header parameter in RAML

Tags: mule, raml

I need to define a response header parameter that would be common for all the 2xx response codes in the RAML API.

I only found a way to define the parameter per each HTTP code like this:

```
 responses:
  200:
   headers:
    X-Transaction-Id:
      type: string
```

But I need to do something like this:

```
 responses:
      [200-300):
       headers:
        X-Transaction-Id:
          type: string
```

Any help pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot do that. You need to declare each status code separately.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try implementing it as a resource type in a library.

```
#%RAML 1.0 Library
usage: |
  All common response types...
types:
  common-response:
    type: object
    properties: 
      key1: string
      key2: string

resourceTypes: 
  common_response_types:
    description: Common response types for API
    get?:
      responses:
        200:
          body:
            application/json:
              type: common-response
              example: !include examples/example-response.raml
        201:
          body:
            application/json:
              type: common-response
              example: !include examples/example-response.raml
        300:
          body:
            application/json:
              type: common-response
              example: !include examples/example-response.raml
    post?:
      responses:
        200:
          body:
            application/json:
              type: common-response
              example: !include examples/example-response.raml
        201:
          body:
            application/json:
              type: common-response
              example: !include examples/example-response.raml
        300:
          body:
            application/json:
              type: common-response
              example: !include examples/example-response.raml
    patch?:
      responses:
        200:
          body:
            application/json:
              type: common-response
              example: !include examples/example-response.raml
        201:
          body:
            application/json:
              type: common-response
              example: !include examples/example-response.raml
        300:
          body:
            application/json:
              type: common-response
              example: !include examples/example-response.raml
    delete?:
      responses:
        200:
          body:
            application/json:
              type: common-response
              example: !include examples/example-response.raml
        201:
          body:
            application/json:
              type: common-response
              example: !include examples/example-response.raml
        300:
          body:
            application/json:
              type: common-response
              example: !include examples/example-response.raml
```

The you can call it using this.

```
uses:
  common_responses: libraries/common-responses.raml

/getuser:
  type: common_responses.common_response_types
```

Comment: Why did you restrict your solution to the 3 codes only?

Comment: ... and answering your question. Because it is required to store the value it in the response header, not in the body.

Comment: Not sure if you are referring to the solution, but its just an example of how to do it, therefore code snippet.